# Why I got empty object on Angular route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why I got empty object from `ActivatedRoute` params and how to fix that?

```
  routeId$ = this.route.params.pipe(
    tap((params) => console.log(params)), // <--- {}
    pluck('id')
  );
```

I defined the `:id` in the route of the children:

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: OrdersComponent,
        children: [{ path: ':id', component: OrderComponent }], <-- here.
      },
    ]),
```

Because I want to use facade, I declared it in the `providers` to have facade instance for the component:

```
...
providers: [FooFacade],
})
export class OrderComponent {
  constructor(private facade: FooFacade) {}
  doWork() {
    console.log('doWork');
    this.facade.doWork();
  }
```

`FooFacade` is using the service.

I try to find why I got an empty object and not the id so I found out that works:

```
 routeIdWorks$ = this.route.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.params.pipe(
    tap((params) => console.log(params)),
    pluck('id')
  );
```

But it's not the ideal solution because I have to specify alot of `firstChild`. also a function that aggrigate firstChild feel worng.

So there is a way to make this to work?

```
  routeId$ = this.route.params.pipe(
    tap((params) => console.log(params)),
    pluck('id')
  );
```

I also defined those options in the router root:

```
  {
        paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always', <---??
        initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
        enableTracing: false,
      }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hc8cva?file=src/app/foo.service.ts)

Comment: Not entirely sure why you wanted to make in that way. But i think part of the problem is you are injecting the servies in root and then as well within the component. here is an example where i removed injection root and just did it from the ordercomponent https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aisjcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.facade.ts,src%2Fapp%2Forder.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: but now I need to provide every service in the `providers`? my facade may use over 20+ services.. I feel this is not ideal solution..

Comment: My way of here is to use Facade. the Facade expose services think of this as public-api. this is what facade means. and it's have it's own instance. every component has it's own facade so I use providers to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure if its an restriction of the activated route. I believe it only works from the component initiated. And hence it kinda works doing what i did. Maybe there is a way to pass in the activated route to the service when using it.

Comment: So because I don't know if it affected only on route or not, I will need to write every service in the providers as rule of thumb.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve an why? Not entirely sure why the facade is needed.

Comment: I made this example is small part from my application. it's simple: my component providers facade that using the services. the logic exist in the services and facade is export every property and function I want from the services.

Comment: In this case in your facade leave out the activatedRoute pretty sure it will only workfrom within the components them selves and in the do work pass the id from there.